# Firefox disables https on many sites

Tags: firefox, https

Firefox shows https protocol striked through in many sites, some of them like youutube or google. It says the site is not secure and sometimes that they have mixed content. If I open these sites in other computer or other browser in sema computer https is correctly enabled.

Sometimes, clicking "enable protection" enables it, sometimes it doen't, and some time it enables it only for a short period.

**EDIT: example certificate in google.es/maps**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Ideas?

Comment: someone might be tampering with your dns. add `namserver 8.8.8.8` to the top of /etc/resolv.conf. after clear browser cache and try again

Comment: Please post details of the certificates used for the sites with HTTPS struck through. Instructions: http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Web-Browser-Firefox-View-Certificate-Detail.html

Comment: @ptetteh227 wouldn't that happen then in all borwosers?

Comment: @Melebius added some captures

Comment: @K.Weber Thank you for the screenshots. `www.google.es` does obviously not match the pattern `*.google.com` in CN. Does the same CN appear in other browsers, too? Could you specify which other browsers you have tried?

Comment: @Melebius  The Cert has a section for 'Certificate Subject Alternative Name' that includes google.es

Comment: yh. in that case it would affect all the browsers. what warnings did the browser give? You can try changing networks also to see if it fixes the issue

Comment: I have tried Vivaldi and Chromium with no problems. Most of the times I get warning "This site has mixed content" which is very improbable in the case of google or youtube. This is a PC, not laptop, in an office, I don't have options to change network

Comment: what version of firefox?

Comment: Firefox quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit) for Ubuntu